# Overflow scroll isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3 with SVG. I try to make text wrapping in to the circle shape using a `div`. But If text content is too long(Over than div size), It should have scroller bar to see more text content. Here is my code.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJOeyy

Main.js

```
var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var radius = 80;
    var interactiveCircleRadius = 200;
    var testText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, "+
    "sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,"+
    "sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum."+
    "Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."+
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,"+
    "sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."+
    "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum."+
    "Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";

var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
      .on('dragstart', function() {
        console.log('Start Dragging Group');
      }).on('drag', function(d, i) {
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")");
      });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

var interactiveCircleContainer = svg.append("g")
                                                .data([{x:250,y:250}])
                                                .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";})
                                                .attr("class", "interactiveCircle")                                             .call(dragGroup);


interactiveCircleContainer.append("defs").append("pattern")
                                      .attr("id","interactivecircleImage")
                                      .attr("width",1)
                                      .attr("height", 1)
                                      .append("image")
                                      .attr("xlink:href", "https://hdwallpapers.cat/wallpaper_3840x2160/small_bay_sky_cliff_night_nature_oceans_ultra_3840x2160_hd-wallpaper-1835411.jpg")
                                      .attr("width", interactiveCircleRadius)
                                      .attr("height", interactiveCircleRadius)
                                      .attr("preserveAspectRatio","none");

var interactiveCircle = interactiveCircleContainer.append("circle")
                                    .attr("r", interactiveCircleRadius/2)
                                    .attr("id", "interactiveCircle")
                                    .style("stroke", "#FFFFFF")
                                    .style("stroke-width", 3)
                                    .style("fill", "url(#interactivecircleImage)");
var interactiveCircle = interactiveCircleContainer.append("circle")
                  .attr("r", interactiveCircleRadius/2)
                  .style("fill", "url(#interactivecircleImage)");

var forienObj = interactiveCircleContainer.append("foreignObject")
                                      .attr("x",-(interactiveCircleRadius/2))
                                      .attr("y",-(interactiveCircleRadius/2))
                                      .attr("width", 200)
                                      .attr("height", 200)
                                      .append("xhtml:div")
                                      .style("color", "#FFFFFF")
                                      .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
                                      .attr("class", "interactiveCircleTextInner")
                                      // .style("top")
                                      .text(testText);
```

style.css

```
body{
    background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
}

.interactiveCircleTextInner{
  overflow:scroll;
  height:200px;
}
```

The problem is `overflow:scroll` is working but it does not fit in a `div`.

Thanks.

Comment: @Fjodr Yes now i added it :).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Your closing statement is not clear. "What" does not fit in a `div`? And what do you mean by "fit in"? Bear in mind that the foreign object has no reference to the svg so there is no interaction between the contents of the div and the dimensions of the circle. The text in the div will follow normal CSS formatting and positioning relative to it's parent `div` element.

Comment: @CoolBlue Thanks for you comment. I would like to bring text put in to circle that i create in sag element. But sometimes text is too long that why i need scroller bar to see more content. But now I understand a bit because you said "foreign object has no reference to svg". May be I have to find a new solution to solve it or do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, the shape of the `svg` components will not affect the layout of the text and there is no word wrap in `svg` text elements, so you would have to find a clever way to do it in the div with CSS, or do it with javascript.